Using Vue.js in a chrome extension on a dynamically created div
I am a newbie to chrome extensions and my current extension is very vanilla. What I want to do is add the vue.js source file into my extension so that vue can be used in my other scripts. The issue is that no matter where I call the source file, I am getting errors like "Vue is not a constructor". The extension is meant to inject an interactive component into existing DOM and I would like to use Vue if possible.
I have tried including the library in content scripts, in an executeScript and a nested executeScript (which allegedly delays the execution of my other scripts until the library is run), and some other similar techniques to no avail.
Any general advice would also be welcome. Also I saw something about a package.json that seemed promising but I don't know what to think of it right now.

Normally you just add "vue.js" before the main script's name. Show your code (MCVE).

Give a try to this: https://github.com/antfu-collective/vitesse-webext
